# what is intercept in coef of smooth.basis with fourie basis?

Tags: r, coefficients

suppose I have a data like y and I fit a smooth function to this data with Fourier basis

```
  y<- c(1,2,5,8,9,2,5)
  x <- seq_along(y)
  Fo <- create.fourier.basis(c(0, 7), 4)
  precfd = smooth.basis(x,y,Fo)
  plotfit.fd(y, x, precfd$fd)
  precfd <- smooth.basis(x, y, Fo);coef(precfd)
```

the out put of last line gives me this:

```
const 411.1060285
sin1  -30.5584033
cos1    6.5740933
sin2   26.2855849
cos2  -26.0153965
```

I know what is the coefficient but what in const? in original formula there is no constant part as this link say:

http://lampx.tugraz.at/~hadley/num/ch3/3.3a.php

Answer (score 1):

The first basis function in `create.fourier.basis` is a constant function to allow for a non-zero mean (intercept) in the data. From the documentation of the `create.fourier.basis` function:

> The first basis function is the unit function with the value one everywhere. The next two are the sine/cosine pair with period defined in the argument period. The fourth and fifth are the sin/cosine series with period one half of period. And so forth. The number of basis functions is usually odd.

You can drop the first (unit) basis function in `create.fourier.basis` with the argument `dropind = 1`. Below some example code that illustrates which basis functions are used in `create.fourier.basis`. Note: the scaling of the basis functions depends on the `period` argument in `create.fourier.basis`.

### Example 1: non-zero mean

```
library(fda)

## time sequence
tt <- seq(from = 0, to = 1, length = 100)

## basis functions
phi_0 <- 1 
phi_1 <- function(t) sin(2 * pi * t) / sqrt(1 / 2)
phi_2 <- function(t) cos(2 * pi * t)  / sqrt(1 / 2)

## signal
f1 <- 10 * phi_0 + 5 * phi_1(tt) - 5 * phi_2(tt)  
## noise
eps <- rnorm(100)
## data
X1 <- f1 + eps

## create Fourier basis with intercept
four.basis1 <- create.fourier.basis(rangeval = range(tt), nbasis = 3)

## evaluate values basis functions
## eval.basis(tt, four.basis1)

## fit Fourier basis to data
four.fit1 <- smooth.basis(tt, X1, four.basis1)

coef(four.fit1)
```

### Example 2: zero mean

```
## signal
f2 <- 5 * phi_1(tt) - 5 * phi_2(tt)
## data
X2 <- f2 + eps

## create Fourier basis without intercept
four.basis2 <- create.fourier.basis(rangeval = range(tt), nbasis = 3, dropind = 1)

## evaluate values basis functions
## eval.basis(tt, four.basis2)

## fit Fourier basis to data
four.fit2 <- smooth.basis(tt, X2, four.basis2)

coef(four.fit2)
```

Comment: how I know which one is mine?

Comment: Do you mean whether to include a constant term (intercept) or not in the model? If the data has not been preprocessed to have mean zero, it probably makes sense to include the constant basis function. Compare this to including a term for the intercept in a linear model.

Comment: No with compare the link in my question, you gave a different formulla. I am confused

Comment: The first term (`n = 0`) in the Fourier series in your link is also constant and is equal to `a_0`, corresponding to a coefficient with respect to a unit basis function. Check out the Fourier series definitions at wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series, which are all equivalent representations.